# BroadcastReceiver onReceive not working in Service

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, keyevent

Im trying to detect the wired earphone's mic button press while the app is running in background,

- In the below code, i have AudioService.java running as a long running service with a notification, it also has a MyBroadcastReceiver initilization and in MyBroadcastReceiver the button event is handled.
- Im able to detect the event if the button is pressed when the app is running, but not when app is closed (in homescreen or on other app) or screen is off.

heres my MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  private int FOREGROUND_ID = 159753;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
              new String[]{Manifest.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE},
              FOREGROUND_ID);
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AudioService.class);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, intent);

  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                         int[] grantResults)
  {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == FOREGROUND_ID) {
      if (grantResults.length > 0
              && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
      {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "permission granted");
      } else {

        Log.d("MainActivity", "permission denied");
      }

    }
  }


  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Playing audio", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.d("MainActivity", "Pressed!");
      return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
}
```

AudioService.java

```
public class AudioService extends Service {

  private static final String TAG = "AudioService";
  private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
  private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "AudioServiceChannel";

//  private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;
  private MyBroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    // Create the broadcast receiver to listen for ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON
    mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();

    // Register the broadcast receiver with the intent filter for ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // Create the notification channel and builder
    createNotificationChannel();
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("Audio Service")
            .setContentText("Listening for mic button presses")
            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setOngoing(true);

    // Start the service as a foreground service with the notification
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

    // Return START_STICKY so the service will be automatically restarted if it is killed by the system
    return START_STICKY;
  }
}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
      if (event != null && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
              && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Mic button pressed");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Media_control_test1">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".AudioService" />

        <!-- Define your receiver element here -->
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```